# How can I open an image as a layer and not a background?

Tags: photoshop-cs5

When opening an existing image in Photoshop CS5 (and all other versions I've worked with), it wants to open with the image as a background, but I want it to be a layer.  I am always having to double click the background to convert it to a layer and this is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can open images "as layers" if their filetype has layer-support. So opening PSD files gives you the layers.

JPG's, PNG's etc. don't have layers, so there technically just is a background. Therefore, opening as a layer would actually make changes to the image, hence it would be in a different format than it was when you've opened it. And changing formats automatically is, to my knowledge, not supported.

Comment: But my question is "open as layer".  If I can convert it to a layer, it would be nice to open it as a layer.

Comment: A layer is just different from the background. If you would convert it to a layer automatically, it would alter the image, even without actually changing anything. That would be like always scaling pictures to 50% while importing them. You wouldn't want  that either.

Comment: My logic is that, if you're going to open an image in PS, you're going to be doing something other than just drawing lines on a flat image.  An option to open images as layers by default would be nice and an option that I could conceive of them having in PS somewhere.

Comment: In Photoshop there's a golden rule: work as undestructive as possible. As a result, in most cases there's no need to conver the background. The correct workflow would be to draw (or do whatever is needed) in a layer on top of the background. If you really need to edit the source image itself, you would duplicate it, which gives you the layer you want. This works in most cases.